# Need a list of buttons to float to the right of an image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have some simple HTML and CSS written.  I'd like to get a list of buttons to the right side of an image.

I've tried using `float` and `display: inline`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="img/placeholder.png" />
             </div>
            <div id="controls-container">
                <div class="controls">Start</div>
                <div class="controls">Right</div>
                <div class="controls">Back</div>
                <div class="controls">Down</div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="footer-container">
        <footer>
            <h5>footer</h5>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




.main{
    background: yellow;
}

#image img {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
}

#controls-container{
    background: pink;
}

.footer-container {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

I've highlighted the container for everything but the footer as yellow.  The container holding the buttons are pink.  I've done this to help me understand what's happening to the containers as I test things out.

For float, I've tried floating the buttons-container to the right.  This results in the buttons going to the right of the page, and it seems to somehow disassociate itself from the main container as it is no longer highlighted in yellow.

I've also tried floating the img to the left.  This seems to be the best help so far, except that the yellow background has disappeared.  What happened to the rest of my container? I've tried using margin-top to move the buttons down towards the middle of the image but both the image and the button's margins seem to be altered.

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `display: flex;` to do this. It's much easier to get alignment done with `flex` This is a sample code.

I have added `align-items: flex-start` to your `controls-container` so that it will only take up the space from the top. If you want the container to take the full height along with your `image-container` feel free to remove that code. Also I have removed your ids and used classes to reference the styles and I would advise you to do the same. Hope it helps you.

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">

  <div class="container main">

    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="img/placeholder.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="controls-container">
      <div class="controls">Start</div>
      <div class="controls">Right</div>
      <div class="controls">Back</div>
      <div class="controls">Down</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <h5>
      Footer
    </h5>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.main {
  background: yellow;
}

.image-container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
}

.controls-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: pink;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/fq8t3ndw/

Comment: Thank you very much, just out of curiosity, what is the reasoning behind the spaces in the class names, for example: <div class="d-flex flex-column"> or <div class="container main">?  Also, I will heed your advice and use class names instead of ids, thank you!

Comment: Basically a space between the class names means that there are two different classes that are being referenced. For example for the div tag I am calling the d-flex class and also the flex-column class. This way you can call multiple classes instead of having to write chunks of styling code in one single class and using it. Also it means you don't need to add an id if your want to style a specific div only. Instead you can just use a different class by having a space between

Answer (score 0):

The other way around is to use `position`.I have just tweaked your code, below is the snippet please have a look at it.

```css
.main {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative
}

#image img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
}

#controls-container {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.controls {
  display: inline;
}

.footer-container {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="image">
        <img src="img/placeholder.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="controls-container">
        <div class="controls">Start</div>
        <div class="controls">Right</div>
        <div class="controls">Back</div>
        <div class="controls">Down</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <footer>
      <h5>footer</h5>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am going to do more research on display:flex and positions to use instead of floats.

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer if it had helped you. Thanks @brownc0at

Comment: Unfortunately it says it won't be displayed because I dont have 15 upvotes, but internally it did. So it says.